# ModuleNotFoundError when importing pyarrow

Tags: python

I'm facing on import error when trying to upgrade by pyarrow dependency. More particularly, it fails with the following import:

`from pyarrow import dataset as pa_ds`

This will give the following error

> File "[ENV]/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/dataset.py", line 24,
> in     from pyarrow._dataset import (  # noqa
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow._dataset'

I'm having this issue with both pyarrow 3.0.0 and 2.0.0. The same import works on pyarrow 1.0.1 though. I installed pyarrow through conda. Really don't know what went wrong here.

Comment: Can you try installing pyarrow through the conda-forge channel?  `conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow`?

Comment: Also getting this issue when trying to use Dask to store a parquet file. Pyarrow 3.0.0, installed through `conda`. Just tried to install through conda-forge as well.

Comment: Oddly enough, I do *not* have this issue with pandas (so my workaround was to turn my dask dataframe into a pandas dataframe). Dask version is 2021.01.1, Pandas version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 2):

This fixed that error for me. Note that I'm building from [source](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/docs/source/developers/python.rst) though.

```
$ export PYARROW_WITH_DATASET=1
```

Before:

```
>>> import pyarrow
>>> import pyarrow.dataset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/diana/workspace/arrow/python/pyarrow/dataset.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pyarrow._dataset import (  # noqa
```

After:

```
$ cd workspace/arrow/python/
$ export PYARROW_WITH_DATASET=1
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
$ python
>>> import pyarrow
>>> import pyarrow.dataset
>>> 
>>> print("happy dance!")
```